# Cannot verify digital signature with Java on windows x86 signed on linux x64

Tags: java, digital-signature

I'm having hard time to find the reason of the problem.
The core of the problem is that Signature.verify always returns false.
Signature created on Linux box with x64 architecture and I verify on Windows x86.

Below is the code for signing

```
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
dsa.initVerify(getPublicKey());

byte[] licenseeB = licensee.trim().toUpperCase().getBytes("UTF-8");
dsa.update(= merge(0, encodedLicenseB, licenseeB));            
return dsa.verify(signature);
```

This is code for signature

```
byte[] encodedLicenseB = license.getEncoded();
byte[] licenseeB = license.getLicensee().trim().toUpperCase().getBytes("UTF-8");
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
dsa.initSign(getPrivateKey());
dsa.update(merge(0, encodedLicenseB, licenseeB));
byte[] signature = dsa.sign();
```

Signing and verifying code on from IDE always works. No exceptions appears.

Please share any ideas.

Thanks !

Comment: How is licensee defined or what does license.getLicensee() return. Is it a string? If so and it contains line separators then those separator are different fow Windows and Unix and as a result you're signing and verifying different byte arrays.

Comment: Andrei, Licensee is a string and it doesn't contain any separators - I used simple TEST string. I compared byte arrays - they are the same. Going to switch to MD5withRSA in order to find consistent signature. Thanks for your idea!

Comment: What about "byte[] encodedLicenseB = license.getEncoded();"? There's no such method in String. I hope you checked both byte arrays: encodedLicenseB and licenseeB.